# Excel Count Day and Year

Tags: excel, excel-2010

In my spreadsheet I have a column that contains a date/time.

I have one field where I am counting the number of Monday's that appear in this column, but also want to create a separate count by year. My current formula is:

```
 =SUM(--(WEEKDAY(D1:D1353)=2))
```

How would I alter this so that in the same cells `D1:D1353` I can narrow it down so that I am counting the number of times a Monday occurred in, say, 2008? or 2009?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I am assuming this is an array formula entered with <kbd>CTL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. If that's the case, you should be able to add criteria with multiplication:

```
{=SUM(--(WEEKDAY(D1:D1353)=2)*(YEAR(D1:D1353)=2008))}
```

---

*Note: If you multiply `*` boolean values, this is "equivalent" to having `AND` conditions between your statements. If you wish to use `OR` logic, you can use addition `+`. For example, the same formula with addition `+`:*

```
{=SUM(--(WEEKDAY(D1:D1353)=2)+(YEAR(D1:D1353)=2008))}
```

*Would translate to: Give me all dates in range `D1:D1353` that are Monday's **or** dates in range `D1:D1353` equal to 2008.*

Comment: you are absolutely correct. This was entered as an array formula. 

This worked. For some reason I was thinking when I tried it that I needed a comma instead of the *.... thanks!